# Rails - find record with highest month/year

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm kinda stuck in a select query question:
I have a Bill model, which contains two integer attributes: month and year. I would like to retrieve the more recent record (highest date) so I can check an attribute value on it. Any ideas for solving that problem, since month and year are independent attributes?
Thanks!

Comment: `.order (:year, :month)`

Comment: what are the datatypes of the `year` and `month` columns?

Comment: @AndreyDeineko both integer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Bill.order('year DESC, month DESC').first
```